# Is It Possible to Create a Bootable Ubuntu Install Within Chrubuntu?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, chromebook, chromeos

I'm currently using Chrubuntu on my C720 Chromebook, but want to create a bootable Linux USB key. The problem is that I can't seem to do this from within Ubuntu once I've loaded it and obviously can't do it in Chrome OS at all.

I haven't got easy access to Windows or a Mac, so would prefer to do it within Chrubuntu if possible. I've tried it with both an SD card and a USB thumb drive with UNetbootin and the disk creators available through the software centre. Both throw errors, basically telling me I don't have permission, or just "Installation failed".

Right now, I have a downloaded ISO and a 32GB SD card and USB key.

The reason I'd like to do this is that I need to do some software development for university (the only serious programming this academic year) and would like a bootable environment for both my Chrome devices and for use elsewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, you have a C720 with Chrubuntu installed. Do you want to create a complete install of Ubuntu in the USB or a Live USB, that can be used to install Ubuntu into other PCs?

Comment: I want to create a bootable install of Ubuntu that I can run on multiple machines and save applications and files to, but not install it on other machines. Not a Live USB.
The idea is to then remove Chrubuntu from my machine, but have it in dev mode to save space and allow USB booting.

Comment: Just to be sure, C720 has its own peculiarities. An install customized for C720 may not work in another machine and vice versa. The basic steps are: First create a Live USB (or Live SD, if your final destination is the USB). Then boot from the live USB or SD and install Ubuntu in the SD or USB (whichever you are not using in the Live mode.

Comment: No, it's for general booting. As long as it'll boot within the C720 and the ASUS Chromebox, I'll be happy.

Comment: Check out all the answers to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator you can't do it from within Chrubuntu unless you intall Virtual Box as in the first answer above. You can boot from a Live USB and install into the SD card or vice versa.

Comment: Once you have a generic full install of Ubuntu in the USB or SD, I can help you with some of the customizations you will need such as to get the touchpad work when using the USB/SD with C720.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's appreciated. I'll have a look at that later and post here again if I need more assistance.